What is this contraption off the wing of a US Navy DHC-6?
I came across this image of a US Navy CIRPAS (Center for Interdisciplinary Remotely Piloted Aircraft Studies) DHC-6 Twin Otter.
On one wing there seems to be a thing attached with a few pods and holes. It doesn't seem to be there on the other wing. Does anyone know what this is?
Seems to be some sensor array but for what all exactly? What's the data it collects?
Image of the same is below -


That's a contraption all right.

@DarthPseudonym Looks more like a doodad to me.

That's clearly a chemtrail generator

It's an NSA mind-reading thingamajig!  Better get out your tinfoil hat 

@Richard Don't be ridiculous. That is obviously too small to be a chemtrail generator.  That is an infuser that injects the chemicals into the water used to create the chemtrails, not the chemtrail generator itself

It for scientific missions related to the atmosphere, e.g. to evaluate the impact of aerosols on different atmospheric elements like anvil-cirrus cloud formation or storms development.

Source.
Aerosols' effects are not well known, but they might be a large contributor to radiative forcing (global warming) as they play the role of seeds for cloud formation. This field has been actively researched for decades.
Some sensors during one of the missions:

Source.
One of the sensor in your picture (passive cavity aerosol spectrometer probe),

PCASP 1, source. It's a spectrometer:

Sample air enters the forward-facing inlet and decelerates by ~10x. Side-facing skarf tube provides suction for continuous flushing of the air to provide fast time response.

The instrument is used to determine the:

Size distribution and concentration of aerosol particles ~0.1 to 3.0 micrometer diameter in 30 size bins


This aircraft (N83NX), like the instruments attached to the hardpoints, has been used by different US entities, both military and civilian. See CIRPAS Platforms, Instrumentation in Demand

Twin Otter (DH-6) research aircraft operated by the Center for Interdisciplinary Remotely Piloted Aircraft Studies (CIRPAS) at the Naval Postgraduate School in Monterey, California. The aircraft supports atmospheric and oceanographic research for Office of Naval Research, National Science Foundation, Department of Energy, National Oceanographic and Atmospheric Administration, NASA, and others. (Naval Postgraduate School)

Source.
It is currently flying as 76-2256 for the Naval Postgraduate School’s (NPS) Center for Interdisciplinary Remotely-Piloted Aircraft Studies (CIRPAS), a school of the US Navy:

Source.

Reminds me of when DeHav Canada tried to market a counter-insurgency Twin Otter that had hard points for rocket or gun pods, A NightSun searchlight, an optical gunsight for the pilot, plus a slide-out .50 cal shooting out the folding cargo door.  A chum actually went on gunnery runs with it as a copilot. Don't think they sold any.

@JohnK Sounds like an update, slightly lighter, version of the AC-47. Probably could be pretty effective in a world without MANPADS.

Oh a much much lighter version of an AC-47. But also able to attack directly, not just orbit a target.

Those are instruments used in the jaw-breaking multi-level acronym  RACORO (Routine ARM (Atmospheric Radiation Measurement) Aerial Facility (AAF) Clouds with Low Liquid Water Depths (CLOWD) Optical Radiative Observations) study which was

an investigation of continental boundary layer clouds

Run by the US Department of Energy.
It had many instruments (not all at the same time):

CAPS (Cloud, Aerosol Precipitation Spectrometer)
FSSP (Forward Scattering Spectrometer Probe)
2D CIP (2D Cloud Imaging Probe)
2D-S (2D Stereo Probe)
CIN (Cloud Integrating Nephelometer)
LWC (Liquid-Water Content; Gerber, CIN, SEA, CAPS Hot Wire)
CPCs (Condensation Particle Counters)
etc

For a complete list see the RACORO Data Guide

I guess it's an improvement over RARMAAFCLOWDORO, technically...

So this is how they measure chemtrails then, rather than creating them ?  :¬)
